# what are the ways to get texts on image without using "position:absolute"?

Tags: css, image, text, position

Is it the only way to get texts on images?
    position:absolute;
    top:0; (at 0 or wherever the image is..)

Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Position has nothing to do with getting text to show

Comment: You should post code of what you've tried. What's wrong with using position absolute for this? Another way to do this would be to add a background image on the element containing the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the html layout, there are other options. Use background image as  toast said in comment. Also can use a negative margin. Like this example:

```css
.myimage{
  background:red;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
    
.mytext{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red block" width="100" height="100" class="myimage" />
<div class="mytext">
[SOME TEXT]
</div>
```